# Why doesn't cant it copy folders and only does files

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that takes source address, destination address and an `ArrayList`, then it goes through the giver Source folder and check each file with the ArrayList items and if they have the same name, then it copies the the destination with the exact same folder structure (so it makes folders in needed). All works till here. But it gives error if the item of the ArrayList is a folder name. Some how It can't find that folder, and comes up with errors.

Here is my code:

```
public class Syncer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File source = new File("D:\\Documents\\A X");
        File destination = new File("D:\\Documents\\A X Sample");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("third");

        folderCrawler(source, destination, list);
    }

    public static void folderCrawler(File src, File dest, ArrayList<String> filesToCopy){
        if(src.isDirectory()){
            String[] children = src.list();
            for(String file:children){

                if(filesToCopy.contains(file)){
                    File from = new File(src, file);
                    File to = new File(dest, file);
                    dest.mkdirs();

                    try{
                        copy(from, to);
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                else{System.out.println("Not Found");}
            }

            for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++){
                folderCrawler(new File(src, children[i]), new File(dest, children[i]), filesToCopy);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void copy(File src, File dest) throws IOException{
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);


        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        System.out.println("Copied: " + src.getName());
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

It does compile and goes down the list till it finds the array item same as the current source, and then stops.
Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Documents\A X\folder2\tohi\third (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at syncer.Syncer.copy(Syncer.java:61)
    at syncer.Syncer.folderCrawler(Syncer.java:45)
    at syncer.Syncer.folderCrawler(Syncer.java:55)
    at syncer.Syncer.folderCrawler(Syncer.java:55)
    at syncer.Syncer.main(Syncer.java:31)
```

In my other mathchine I get same error but it is `(Is a directory)` instead of `(Access denied)`.

So any idea to make it work even if a folder is given. So it will copy the folder with its inner files ?

Comment: Folders cannot be copied the same way you copy files. The way to do it, is to check whether the file is a folder, and then create a new folder at the destination, and copy each file from the source folder to the destination folder. That is how your operating system does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don' have enough rep to comment.

Have a look at apache commons [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). They have a lot of copy functions so you don't have to implement them yourself.

Comment: Wow amazing. I spent hours to do all the functionalists that this FileUtils does all. :( Thanks for your answer. Life saver.